# Асинхронность в winsock

Tags: c, winsock, c++, асинхронность

Вопрос таков: как перевести сокет в асинхронный режим?
В интернете информация крайне скупая.

Comment: http://www.uinc.ru/articles/24/index.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот на MSDN есть [статейка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5).